# Can't access Rasperberry Pi over the internet

Tags: ppp, 3g, wvdial

I set up an R-Pi 3G Modem combo with wvdial and it's working perfectly. I can access everything on the internet from the Pi. But when I try to access the Pi from the internet there is nothing, zero connection. As far as I can tell there is no firewall so I have no idea what blocks the data. If I connect the Pi to my LAN I can access it through my local network.

Comment: Can you add more details, what are the steps you have made or how do you know that there isn't a connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly, your 3G provider gives you a private IP address from one of these ranges

- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255

In this case, you're behind ISP's NAT and can't access Pi from the internet, but you can access the internet from Pi.